# c# Sending email using POST and Mime

Tags: c#, post, mime

I am writing a program whereby my supervisor wants me to make use of their internal sandbox email system.

Essentially, the code I have so far is:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

Stream os = null;
byte[] Bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("From: no-reply@foo.com\n" + "To: foo@foo.com\n" + "Subject: test\n" + "jkjlkjkj\n");
try
{
  request.ContentLength = Bytes.Length;
  os = request.GetRequestStream();
  os.Write(Bytes, 0, Bytes.Length);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  Console.WriteLine("error");
}
```

This works fine and send the e-mail as expected.  But how can I send attachments using this method?  They are likely to open be small minidump files.

Thanks.

Comment: This will very much depend on how the system expects the attachments to be formatted. `WebRequest` is just used for sending an HTTP request.

Comment: You have custom email script in the uri variable. This is not standard way to send email. So you have to look at the script located at uri variable, and see if it even supports sending attachments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a standard email protocol just look for the specifications on how an attachment is sent in an email. I just found this example in PHP that creates a message with an attachment, maybe it will work the same way in .NET (changing the calls):

Try adding those lines on the Bytes array:

Content-Type: application/zip; name="attachment.zip"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment
attachmentContents

where attachmentContents is a base64 encoded dump of the file (obviously, change the names and mime types according to what you're sending.

I took this code from here http://www.webcheatsheet.com/PHP/send_email_text_html_attachment.php#attachment

Hope it helps

Hope it helps.